# Brew doctor: dyld: Library not loaded & Error: No available formula for zlib

Tags: zlib, homebrew, dylib, dyld

When I `brew doctor` I get the following errors:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Error: No available formula for zlib
```

The file `libltdl.7.dylib` is not in my /usr/lib directory, but there are several other `.dylib` files.

I'm running 10.8.1 with the latest version of Xcode (4.4.1) and its Command Line Tools installed.

Any idea how to solve these errors?

Comment: I removed php from brew entirely and then did a brew clean and then reinstalled and that fixed it. The OP is talking about PHP here and many of the people's answers below are not related to the PHP error but a brew error. Just remove everything related to your problem and then "brew clean" and reinstall everything and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to re-install libtool by:

```
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```

If that doesn't help, try removing libtool completely, and then retry the steps above:

```
brew uninstall libtool
```

---

If it still doesn't work after trying the steps above, check to see if you have the **DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH** variable defined somewhere on the system (e.g. ~/.profile) and try unsetting it before trying the steps above again.

---

Other commands which could be useful for identifying the issue:

```
$ libtool --version
$ whereis libtool
$ set | grep DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
$ echo $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I had to do `brew uninstall libtool` and then run your command and everything worked fine again.

Comment: +1 to the above comment (and answer). I too had to uninstall my problem package then reinstall via the provided answer.

Comment: I had one issue when I tried to find out the version of libtool: error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --version ........ My Xcode version is 7.3.0

Comment: I made it without `--universal` and I'm Sierra 10.12.4;

Answer (score 11):

For me it works with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/lib/libltdl.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
```

Comment: This worked for me - my route had been via an update to OSX Mavericks followed by a Ruby update to 2.1.1 (since anything prior doesnt seem to compile under Mavericks) and then rmagick/imagemagick falling over, requiring reinstall of ImageMagick via brew and forcing rmagick to v 2.13.2 (since 2.13.4 gave issues)

Comment: Best way I've found to handle these kinds of issues; if the DYLD library didn't get installed the first time, it generally doesn't get installed the nth time.

Answer (score 11):

if you have an error about pcre like this :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.7.0/libexec/bin/watchman
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

you need to link pcre.

```
brew link --overwrite pcre
```

Comment: this is exactly what I had. Thank you Diego

Comment: Or just `brew install pcre`.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

See: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/pull/219

Answer (score 3):

None of them work I personally reinstalled Watchman like so:

```
brew uninstall watchman
brew reinstall watchman
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
brew install node
```

Found the hint in this article: https://goulet.dev/posts/node-dyld-library-not-loaded-icu4c/

Answer (score 1):

```
xcode-select --install
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install pcre
brew install libtool
```

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solve it with this link's file:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dyli
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from kenorb is what worked for me + a little extra for safe measure:
    brew update
freetype didn't have symlinks so:
brew link freetype
various other solutions I tried:

```
brew remove imagemagick
brew link jpeg libpng
brew install imagemagick
brew install libtiff
brew uninstall libtool
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```

There's a good chance that this wasn't all necessary if I had found

```
brew uninstall libtool
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```

first. But I thought I would post my full process in case anyone runs into issues

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to fix XQuartz as brew doctor asked me too:

Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.6) is outdated
   Please install XQuartz 2.7.8:
     https://xquartz.macosforge.org

It worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error in the process of installing AFNI. Installing PyQt, as suggested [here](https://afni.nimh.nih.gov/afni/community/board/read.php?1,149775,150178#msg-150178%22here%22), fixed the issue resulting from OSX 10.11 compatibility.

```
brew install pyqt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had: 

`% neato
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Documents/dev/anaconda/bin/neato
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      neato`

And the fix was 

`% echo $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/me/anaconda/lib:/usr/lib
% export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

(and then add the export to a `.bashrc` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

First :

```
brew uninstall libffi
```

Then :

```
brew install libffi
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.2-162/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: image not found
```

`brew unlink python && brew link python`  and boom, fixed.