# Homebrew updated zlib and broke everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew, zlib

So a `brew update` updated zlib from 1.2.7 to 1.2.8. Yay.

Later I noticed there was an issue running `bundle`. I was getting a `LoadError` for zlib.

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/zlib.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
  Referenced from: /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/zlib.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/zlib.bundle (LoadError)
```

`brew doctor` says:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

Tried `brew tap homebrew/dupes` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323252/brew-doctor-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-no-available-formula-for-zlib), got `Error: Already tapped!`, of course

Next tried `rvm reinstall 2.0.0`. Now `bundle` works but `rails s` still does not.

```
/Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.so.1.2.7 (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

## Update

Managed to get my everything working, for now, with a `cp /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.so.1.2.8 /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.so.1.2.7`. The jankiest of fixes. If anyone has a real solution to this I'd be much obliged.

Comment: It's an utterly filthy fix, but it works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, I do propose the following:

1. `brew remove php53` (or php54) You can even be more aggressive if
   needed, just to make sure that no previous installation of php is on
   your Mac.
2. (optional) do a `brew cleanup`. I did not do it and things have been
   fixed.
3. `brew install php53` (or php54)

Then, `php -v` will give you a nice:

```
PHP 5.3.23 (cli) (built: May  6 2013 16:18:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

No more complaints about a missing lib or anything else.

Comment: This did the trick, though I had to do the same with a few php54 dependents as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me:

```
brew untap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

Then continue:

```
brew install zlib
brew list zlib
```

Reference: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/205

Answer (score 1):

Today, after running `brew upgrade`, git stopped working. I also got a load error for zlib, when I try to run `git`. After the following:

1. `brew remove git`
2. `brew cleanup`
3. `brew install git`

the problem is gone and git is working again. Thanks @Stephane

I think this might be helpful for others too, so posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove php (php54 for me), cleanup, tap josegonzalez/php, then reinstall php.

```
brew remove php54
brew cleanup
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew install php54
```