# image not found - error plotting decision tree using dot

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to follow along [this bit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) from scikit-learn about plotting a decision tree using `graphviz`.

When I run

```
(datasci)benjamins-MacBook-Pro-2:Scripts Ben$ dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf
```

I get the following error message

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
>   Referenced from: //anaconda/envs/datasci/bin/dot   Reason: image not
>   found Trace/BPT trap: 5

There is definitely a file in my working directory named "iris.dot", so I'm not sure why I'm getting an "image not found" error. Any suggestions?

Specs: Mac OSX 10.11.1, Anaconda virtual environment with graphviz 2.38.0

Comment: The "image not found" message may be referring to `/usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib` rather than to `iris.dot`. I suggest confirming that the dynamic library exists. If it doesn't there may have been an installation problem.

Comment: @Simon yep.  I eventually found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323252/brew-doctor-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-no-available-formula-for-zlib) which helped me.