# Graphviz.Source not rendering in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: scikit-learn, ipython, graphviz, jupyter-notebook

After exporting a .dot file using scikit-learn's handy `export_graphviz` function.

I am trying to render the dot file using Graphviz into a cell in my Jupyter Notebook:

```
import graphviz
from IPython.display import display

with open("tree_1.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))
```

However the out[ ] is just an empty cell.

I am using graphviz `0.5` (pip then conda installed), iPython `5.1`, and Python `3.5`
The dot file looks correct here are the first characters:

`digraph Tree {\nnode [shape=box, style="filled", color=`

iPython display seems to work for other objects including Matplotlib plots and Pandas dataframes.

I should note the example on Graphviz' [site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) also doesn't work.

Comment: this was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323252/brew-doctor-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-no-available-formula-for-zlib/17761170#17761170)

Answer (score 14):

It's possible that since you posted this, changes were made so you might want to update your libraries if that's possible.

The versions of relevance here I used are:

Python 2.7.10

IPython 5.1.0

graphviz 0.7.1

If you have a well formed .dot file, you can display it to the jupyter out[.] cell by the following:

```
import graphviz

with open("tree_1.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()

# remove the display(...)

graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

Answer (score 4):

this solution allows you to insert DOT text directly (without saving it to file first)

```py
# convert a DOT source into graph directly
import graphviz 
from IPython.display import display
    
source= '''\
digraph sample {
A[label="AL"]
B[label="BL"]
C[label="CL"]
A->B
B->C 
B->D
D->C
C->A
}
'''
print (source)
gvz=graphviz.Source(source)
# produce PDF
#gvz.view()
print (gvz.source)
display(gvz)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use pydotplus.

```
import pydotplus
```

by (1.1) Importing the .dot from outside

```
pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_file("clf.dot")
```

or (1.2) Directly using the .export_graphviz output

```
dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt = clf.fit(x,y)
dt_graphviz = tree.export_graphviz(dt, out_file = None)

pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dt_graphviz)
```

(2.) and than display the pyplot graph using

```
from IPython.display import Image

Image(pydot_graph.create_png())
```

Comment: the last two lines seem to not do much, where is this png created? In the `/tmp/` folder?

Answer (score 2):

try to reinstall graphviz

```
conda remove graphviz
conda install python-graphviz
graphviz.Source(dot_graph).view()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
graphviz.Source(dot_graph).view()
```

Comment: Please offer some, little bit, of explanation to improve the quality of your answer. See here for help on [Writing a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @kapfy May I request you to please add some context around your answer. It is difficult to make-out anything with a code-snippet only answer. It will be helpful for the asker as well as the other readers.