# Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/fmt/lib/libfmt.9.dylib

Tags: homebrew

When I use `bilix` I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/bin/bilix", line 5, in <module>
    from bilix.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bilix/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import *
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bilix/download/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .downloader_bilibili import DownloaderBilibili
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bilix/download/downloader_bilibili.py", line 9, in <module>
    import bilix.api.bilibili as api
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bilix/api/bilibili.py", line 8, in <module>
    from danmakuC.bilibili import parse_view
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/danmakuC/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import bilibili, niconico
  File "/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/danmakuC/bilibili.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._c.ass import Ass
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/danmakuC/_c/ass.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/fmt/lib/libfmt.9.dylib
 Referenced from: <5A0345A5-2999-38C9-AE6E-DEA86B6F46FD> /Users/whitewater/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/danmakuC/_c/ass.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/fmt/lib/libfmt.9.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/fmt/lib/libfmt.9.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/fmt/lib/libfmt.9.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libfmt.9.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libfmt.9.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
(base) whitewater@MadBookAir ~ %
```

refer to these content to reinstall `libtool` and `libffi` via brew, still report the same error

> - [homebrew - Brew doctor: dyld: Library not loaded & Error: No available formula for zlib - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323252/brew-doctor-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-no-available-formula-for-zlib)
> - [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.6.dylib · Issue #7 · platformio/platform-lattice_ice40 · GitHub](https://github.com/platformio/platform-lattice_ice40/issues/7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another answer I tried: `brew install fmt`. That resolved successfully, but said it was already installed.

Instead I ran `brew reinstall fmt`. This failed with a message that said to reinstall bison.

1. To resolve, run:

   `brew reinstall bison`
2. Then again run:

   `brew reinstall fmt`

That resolved this terribly frustrating error.

Answer (score 0):

deal with `brew install fmt`

> [报错Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/fmt/lib/libfmt.9.dylib · Issue #118 · HFrost0/bilix · GitHub](https://github.com/HFrost0/bilix/issues/118)